# React Native: "Unable to resolve module child_process" when using google-spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-sheets, browser, expo

So, I have a simple expo-react-native project, where I use the google-spreadsheet module.
But when running the project on a device using the "Expo Go" app, it gives me this error:

`[14:20:42] Unable to resolve module child_process from C:\Users\user\Documents\ProjectDirectory\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js: child_process could not be found within the project.`

It was an issue at the beginning but then I started running it in the web browser, which seemed to ignore the problem and work perfectly. Moreover, the google-spreadsheet module worked perfectly when ran out of react-native/expo.

Now, when trying to build the project to android, I get the same error.
I have looked into everything I can find on the internet but there doesn't seem to be a logical solution to this.

I am clueless about what can I do about this error,
any help would be really appreciated.